# is it possible to call more packages in single project,without installing the other packages in emulator/phone.want single apk

Tags: android

is it possible to call more packages in single project,without installing the other packages in emulator/phone,want single apk file..I Kept this code...but is possible when the package is available in emulator/phone..Please suggest me...if that package is not available in emulator/phone

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
            "com.abc.def.packname",
            "com.abc.def.packname.MyActivity"));

  startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use an Intent to launch any Activity, there must be an Activity available to Handle it. This applies for both direct intents that target one particular Activity, and more general intents which would result in a Chooser dialog, like the share intent.

So in short, yes, the package you are referencing must be installed as well, or else your app will crash. If you have access to the source code of the other project, you could combine them into one. If this isn't possible, you could request that the user installs the other app when your app starts.

Comment: But i need to upload only single apk...without uploading all the remaining apks...is it possible?...inserting entire code is not possible because i want to put 5 packages in single project..Please suggest me...

Comment: It is possible to upload just one package. It's just that your app will crash every time it tries to use something from one of the other packages, so you should avoid it.